# How to setup ipv6 on centos?

Tags: centos, ipv6

I bought a dedicated server with ipv6 support, they gave me ipv6 information:

```
IP Address Allocation:
IPv6: xxxx:6c80:0:14::/64
Gateway: xxxx:6c80::1
```

How could I set up and check if ipv6 is working on my server? I am currently using Centos 6.8 and nginx 1.11.

Comment: Ping, ssh, nginx default page? How would you access your server normally?

Comment: yes i use ssh to access my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file. For instance:

```
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6ADDR="2001:db8:d43f:1e97::a28b/64"
IPV6_DEFAULTGW="fe80::205:73ff:fec3:18d9"
IPV6_PRIVACY="no"
```

Then restart networking, e.g. `service network restart` or reboot the computer.

You can see if it's working by pinging an IPv6 enabled host which responds to pings.

```
ping6 -n -c 1 www.google.com
PING www.google.com(2607:f8b0:4006:80e::2004) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4006:80e::2004: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=24.1 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.173/24.173/24.173/0.000 ms
```

You can also set up the IPv6 address and gateway while installing the operating system.